# What are the effects of the doctrine of Cessationism on the church for carrying out the "great commission" of Jesus?

Tags: pneumatology, cessationism, great-commission

Jesus gave the great commission to His disciples (Matt 28:19-20). And Jesus instructed His disciples to tarry in Jerusalem until baptized with the Holy Spirit, and received and clothed power from on high that they will be witnesses of Jesus beginning from Jerusalem to the end of the earth. The Gospel is yet to be preached to the end of the world, and the "power from on high" is as necessary now as it was then.

Comment: What's that passage got to do with the cessationism/continuationism debate?

Comment: Considerably more clarity and detail is required to flesh this out into an answerable enquiry.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which version of cessationism we are talking about. Some sources identify four major "flavors" of cessationism:

[Monergism.com](https://www.monergism.com/topics/spiritual-gifts/cessationists-view):

> In Christian theology, cessationism is the view that the charismatic gifts of the Holy Spirit, such as tongues, prophecy and healing, ceased being practiced early on in Church history. Cessationists usually believe the miraculous gifts were given only for the foundation of the Church, during the time between the coming of the Holy Spirit on Pentecost, c. AD 33 (see Acts 2) and the fulfillment of God's purposes in history, usually identified as either the completion of the last book of the New Testament or the death of the last Apostle.
> Cessationists are divided into four main groups:
>
> - **Concentric Cessationists** believe that the miraculous gifts have indeed ceased in the mainstream church and evangelized areas, but appear in unreached areas as an aid to spreading the Gospel (Luther and Calvin, though they were somewhat inconsistent in this position).
> - **Classical cessationists** assert that the "sign gifts" such as prophecy, healing and speaking in tongues ceased with the apostles and the finishing of the canon of Scripture. They only served as launching pads for the spreading of the Gospel; as affirmations of God's revelation. However, these cessationists do believe that God still occasionally does miracles today, such as healings or divine guidance, so long as these "miracles" do not accredit new doctrine or add to the New Testament canon. Richard Gaffin, John F. MacArthur and Daniel B. Wallace are perhaps the best-known classical cessationists.
> - **Full Cessationists** argue that along with no miraculous gifts, there are also no miracles performed by God today. This argument, of course, turns on one's understanding of the term, "miracle." B. B. Warfield, J. Gresham Machen, F.N. Lee.
> - **Consistent Cessationists** believe that not only were the miraculous gifts only for the establishment of the first-century church, but the so-called fivefold ministry found in Eph. 4 was also a transitional institution (i.e., There are no more apostles or prophets, but also no more pastors, teachers, or evangelists). For more information, click on Wikipedia.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessationism_versus_continuationism#Types_of_cessationism):

> - **Full cessationists** believe that all miracles have ceased, along with any miraculous gifts.
> - **Classical cessationists** assert that the miraculous gifts such as prophecy, healing, and speaking in tongues ceased with the apostles.
>   However, they do believe that God occasionally works in supernatural
>   ways today.
> - **Consistent cessationists** believe that not only were the miraculous gifts only for the establishment of the first-century
>   church, but the need for apostles and prophets also ceased.
> - **Concentric cessationists** believe that the miraculous gifts have indeed ceased in the mainstream church and evangelized areas, but may
>   appear in unreached areas as an aid to spreading the Gospel. Daniel B.
>   Wallace describes himself as a concentric cessationist and describes
>   the other cessationist viewpoints as "linear".

For example, Concentric Cessationists believe that the miraculous gifts of the Spirit still manifest in the mission field, on the cutting edge of evangelism, so this supernatural aspect of the great commission is believed to continue under this view. Other flavors of Cessationism are less open to this possibility to different degrees, as is the case with extreme positions such as *Full Cessationism*, in which not only the miraculous gifts are believed to have ceased, but also all miracles in general.

Comment: This is a useful summary of principal positions within cessationism, +1